# How to auto refresh browser during development when static assets are sent via Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I automatically refresh the browser when I make changes to my client files?  I am building the client using ReactJS.  I am telling my Express server to send the static assets located in my public directory when a GET request is made to "/".

Here is how my server looks:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 1128;

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// static assets
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './../public')));

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`server is listening on port: ${port}`)
);
```

After making changes, webpack bundles everything and outputs everything into the public directory.  Is there a way for the server to watch for changes here so the browser could automatically refresh? If anyone knows how or knows of a better way I'd greatly appreciate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a websocket which notifies clients on file changes. You can detect file changes using `fs.watch()`

Watch file system: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_event_change

Web socket: https://socket.io/ (or your library of choice)

```
socket.on('file_changed', function () {
  location.reload();
});
```

Comment: My client is now listening for changes using sockets but when it runs location.reload() I get an error in my browser saying: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"  

It looks like it's working though in that it's refreshing the browser.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is it actually breaking anything? It's probably cause my code doesn't properly terminate the WS connection.

Comment: I don't believe anything is being broken.  If I manually refresh the browser everything is back to normal.  But yea, it may have something to do with improperly terminating the web socket connection.  I'm not 100% certain though.  If I have any more useful info I'll let you know.  TY!

Comment: Just call `socket.disconnect()` before reloading and it should be gucci. Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted. @RyanSantos