# Is there a way to refresh static files without server restart?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My simple Node.js app serves static files, e.g. html/txt

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

I want to reflect my changes to those files without restarting the app.
I.e. want to be able to modify any txt/help/read.me static files to it's available right away for the clients without restarting the app. How do I do it?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

Comment: thanks Cuchu but how do I let express know that static files updated so it can be refreshed?

Comment: It has been my experience that when you update a file on the server, Express will immediately start serving the new version without any server restart if you have caching flags are set appropriately so that the browser doesn't continue to use its cached version.  Can you describe exactly what situation you tested and had a problem with?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338689/2209876

Comment: I think the OP doesn't mean for it to instantly be in effect on the client side, but, to after reloading, show the latest changes.
Express serves the files as they were when the app was first started.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this way:

```
app.use(express.static('public’, {etag: false}))
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, etags are basically file hashes, so if the file has changed, its etag will also change and the browser won't use a cached version. So I'm not sure how disabling etags helped you here?

Answer (score 1):

To determine if a file has changed, you can use `fs.watch` from the built-in `fs` module. It works like this: `fs.watch('filename_or_directory', function(event, file) {})` . The callback's first parameter is "event", a string which is either "rename" or "change", depending on what type of change happened. The second parameter is the filename that changed.

For the client to automatically know that a change has occurred on the server is a bit more complex. There needs to be some form of communication with the server; you can do this with polling or with web sockets. If you go the socket route, you can use a library like `socket.io` or `ws` to establish a connection between server and client; when the server notices a change in a file from `fs.watch`, it can broadcast that change as a JSON "event object" to all clients, which can then receive the message and determine how to proceed (reload the current page, request updated data via AJAX, ignore it because it's an unrelated file, etc.).

If you go the polling route, you don't need any web socket libraries. You'd just keep track of the timestamp of each change from `fs.watch` in an array, then set up a route like `/api/getChanges` or something. You have the client, at regular intervals, post the timestamp of the last client update to that route, and the server can respond with all change objects in the array after that time.

Note: Express doesn't need to know that a file has changed. It will re-read files as they're requested. It's the client that needs to know when to refresh.

Comment: It does not seem like this is the problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: He's asking how to make Express aware of file changes in static files, but as I noted at the bottom of this answer, that's not necessary. It automatically serves the latest version of static files. Hence I figured he was really wanting to know how to automatically get changed data for display when the files on the server change.

Comment: No, that's not what I think he's asking.  He's asking *"I want to reflect my changes to those files without restarting the app.  I.e. want to be able to modify any txt/help/read.me static files to it's available right away for the clients without restarting the app. How do I do it?"*.  He wants to be able to edit a static file and have the next client request for that file automatically serve the newly edited version.  That's how I read the question.

Comment: Right... which is what I said... and which is what I also pointed out is done automatically... I'm not sure where our miscommunication is?

Comment: I don't see what `fs.watch()` has to do with this question at all and that's what your answer seems to be about.  Plus you dive into notifying the client of a change which is also not something in the question.

Comment: As I said, serving the new version of a changed file is automatically handled and needs no code, but since the OP asked how to do it, I figured he was really asking how to make the new version available/displayed as soon as a change happens on the server. Which is where the watch and notifications come in. I didn't think he'd be asking how to do something that's already done by default, without any code or changes.

Comment: You made an answer that was predominantly about things that are not in the question and now you're defending your answer because you tacked on a note to the end that tries to tell the OP they don't even have a problem.  As you can see from the answer the OP wrote, the issue was with cache settings (as I suggested in my comment), not anything in your answer.